# Calculo en Google Data Studio de tiempo entre eventos capturados

Tags: google-data-studio

Si alguien me puede dar alguna luz la respecto.

Tengo eventos capturados de una App en BigQuery y los analizo en Google Data Studio. Mi problema es que al calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre dos eventos.

Actualmente para hacer mi grafica de tiempo acumulado la estaba sacando en relacion al evento first_open. Pero tengo que calcular el tiempo acumulado desde el segundo evento. Y ahi es donde salta el problema ya que no se como filtrar.

El calculo de mi metrica actual es `DATEtime_DIFF(event_timestamp,user_first_touch_timestamp,SECOND)` con eso se esta sacando el primer grafico.

Pero si quiero tener el tiempo acumulado desde el segundo evento no se como hacerlo, que seria el segundo grafico. Lo correcto es lo que esta en verde ya que el primer evento fue eliminado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue hacer un match del mismo conjunto de datos original y luego se pueden comparar el timestamp de cada evento para sacar su diferencia (este [link](https://www.wissi.fr/blog/analytics/20220216/data-blending-with-google-data-studio-how-to-blend-data-left-right-inner-outer-cross-join/#feature_review) me ayudo).

Teniendo los 2 conjuntos de datos **Onb_sin_IngresoCel** y IngresoCelular**texto en negrita** se crea una variable con la diferencia de tiempos.

```
DATETIME_DIFF(event_timestamp (Onb_sin_IngresoCel),event_timestamp (IngresoCelular),SECOND)
```

Y con esa variable calculada pude realizar el grafico que deseaba de los tiempos acumulados en relacion a un evento en particular.

[image: Funnel Onboarding]